# Collision Handling for moving rectangles

Tags: silverlight, geometry, collision

in my Silverlight 3 application, I display a tree. A self made user control is used for the treenodes, the LineArrow object for the connections. After initial displaying the tree, I want the nodes to move by the following "physical properties"

- there is a gravitational force, that pulls the node down
- there is a force vector to its parent
- it's children draws it to their middle

Naturally, my User Controls will overlap soon. But I do not want them to overlap. In physics terms, I want them to be solid objects and enforce the physical rule that no 2 objects can inhabit the same space.

Any suggestions how to tackle this problem? I do not want to use a physics engine like farseer for this, because the described part is the only physics to be used within my project.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model them as 'nearly solid' objects simply by adding a very large force between them whenever they overlap.  Calculate the center to center vector, normalize it, maybe multiply by the overlap and then apply that as a force to each object.

Even if you don't use the full Farseer library you may still find some useful classes in it like `Vector2`.

Comment: the problem with very large force vectors is that they shot the object to elsewhere, making the system very unstable.

Comment: Maybe you need a greater damping force: at each step multiply velocity by 0.8, say, or add drag proportional to velocity squared.  Without damping or drag it's tough to create a stable system.

Comment: I will probably introduce a cooldown constant, which lowers the force with each step. Additionally, I'll reduce the size of the vectors by dividing it through the length of the biggest vector. So I move the objects in small steps. The objects that collide simply doesn't move.

Comment: I changed it that way, that colliding objects move away from each other with a stronger force and this works well enough. I also use a cooldownconstant to get it stable.

Answer (score 0):

Are your controls of a squarish shape?  Or can you generate bounding boxes?  If so, you could create a System.Windows.Rect struct for each one, and use the Rect.Insersect method to test intersection.

Comment: I use Rect structures for collision detection. The problem isn't the detection, the problem is to properly shove them to avoid overlapping.

Comment: So do you never want them to collide at all?  Do you want them to bounce?  Or just stop moving on collision?

Comment: I want them to bounce. When they collide because of the movement caused by the force vectors, they should bounce so that they try to "uncollide"